# Netsh the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, dns, netsh

I would like to change an IP address in a Wireless network connection with a cmd line.  I have tried:

```
Netsh -c "interface ipv4" set address name=”Wireless Network Connection” static 192.168.168.6 255.255.255.0 192.168.168.168
```

*Note The above cmd belongs all on one line

I'm getting an error saying:
the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

The second question I have is, I would like to know how to set the secondary DNS.  I think this cmd is working for the primary DNS:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers "Wireless Network Connection" static 8.8.8.8 primary validate=no
```

I'm working in Win7 Ultimate 32bit

Comment: Why are you using smart quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax does not appear to be correct. Try:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address "Wireless Network Connection" static 192.168.168.6 255.255.255.0 192.168.168.168
```

and to add secondary DNS:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add dns "Wireless Network Connection" 8.8.4.4 index=2
```

Comment: Thank you answering this.  The static IP worked great.  The second DNS is giving me an error saying "The parameter is incorrect.".  The help for Netsh doesn't have "index" as a option in Win7.

Comment: Index is invalid only in Windows XP. On 7, it's a valid option: " index (from /? help)       - Specifies the index (preference) for the specified DNS server address." Looks like the word 'static' is no longer needed in case of secondary+ entries. Try without 'static' and it will work. I've updated the main reply.

Comment: Thank you very much for resolving the issue.  The cmd line does work great.  Silly me the word add really does add the DNS.  What I really need is replace the DNS.  If there is something in the secondary DNS I would like to remove it and then replace it with a new DNS.

Comment: What I really need is replace the DNS. If there is something in the secondary DNS I would like to remove it and then replace it with a new DNS.

Comment: netsh interface ipv4 delete dns  - this can remove it, you can use index, just like for adding.